# Storing the output in dictionary in php

Tags: php, dictionary

I am working on a PHP program that takes days/month input pairs. How could I store this information in a dictionary keyed on days with an array of months as the value?

Example Input:

```
(31, 'July')
(28, 'April')
(6, 'January')
(19, 'December')
(6, 'May')
```

Example Output:

```
$dict = array(
  6 => array('January', 'May'),
  19 => array('December'),
  28 => array('April'),
  31 => array('July')
)
```

Comment: Maybe. Show some sample output, and give us a more specific idea of what you're looking for as far a storage.  Better yet would be to know how you want to use the information after it's in the array.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the author's question, I have improved the wording and added an example.

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry I could not reply yesterday night, my net connection was  not going well.
This is the correct example which I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called associative arrays in PHP. You can save values for example like this:

```
$key = 'day';
$value = 'month';
$my_array[$key] = $value;
```

You can find more info about working with arrays in manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Based on update of your question - you can also store more values in array for the same key (see added [ ] with meaning of add new item in array):

```
$key = 'day';
$value1 = 'January';
$value2 = 'February';
$my_array[$key][] = $value1;
$my_array[$key][] = $value2;
```

The result array will be:

```
$my_array = array(
    'day' => array('January', 'February')
)
```